# How can I get a Cordova project template working in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, cordova, templates, visual-studio-2015

I want to try my hand at a Cordova based mobile app. In Visual Studio's project templates, under *Other Languages->JavaScript*, there was an option to install the Cordova templates. I ran that, and after a lengthy install, the *JavaScript* template folder is gone, and there is a new *TypeScript* project template node, with one *Blank App (Apache Cordova)* template.

When I chose that template, I get an error message that says:

> The template specified cannot be found. Please check that the full
>   path is correct

This is giving me the probably wrong impression that in VS2015, support for mobile development has only been given lip service, and there is probably a vast amount of DIY work required to get anything done.

What could be wrong that VS is telling me a template that it just installed is missing? I have a default setup of VS2015 with all default folder settings etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing update 2 of Cordova. I didn't want to do a 7gb update so I unchecked the Windows 10 related cross platform components as I was only interested in the Cordova update.

To fix the issue I installed all the options back into Visual Studio 2015. 
I then received a new error when opening a Cordova Project. I looked in the ActivityLog of Visual Studio "SetSite failed for package [ApacheCordovaToolsPackage]"
To fix this issue I delete the ComponentModelCache of VisualStudio
"C:\Users[your user account]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache"

Comment: Ah, the one cache I didn't know of to delete. I ended up re-installing VS though. I had an RC trial version of Pro, then I installed the RTM version of Community, and suddenly the Cordova template works. There are a whole load of other new ones that don't though.